# Arrays of custom type in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql

I have a custom type in Postgres:

```
CREATE TYPE child AS
   (id integer,
    name text,
    surname text,
    age integer);
```

and table

```
CREATE TABLE parent
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  surname text NOT NULL,
  age integer NOT NULL,
  childs child[],
  CONSTRAINT parent_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and I want to get parents which have a child who has a name = "John"

I tried something like that:

```
select id, name
  from parent
where 'John' = any  (select (unnest(childs)).name from parent)
```

but I received all parents. 
I would be so grateful when someone solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to somehow correlate first parent and the seconds parent. Either you can use the query by Vao Tsun or try to use correlated query:

```
select id, name
  from parent as p1
where 'John' = any  (select (unnest(childs)).name from parent as p2 where p1.id = p2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

whould this help?..

```
with un as (
select (unnest(childs)).name, id from parent
) 
select 
  id
, name 
from parent 
join un on un.id = parent.id 
where un.name = 'John'
;
```

Comment: I had to add in 2nd select parent.id and parent.name instead id and name and then it was working, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to see the problem if you alias the tables:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.name
FROM parent p1
WHERE 'John' = ANY (SELECT (UNNEST(p2.childs)).name FROM parent p2)
```

The `WHERE` clause doesn't even mention `p1`; it's looking at an independent copy of the `parent` table. But there's no need to introduce a second copy of the table at all:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM parent
WHERE 'John' = ANY (SELECT (UNNEST(childs)).name)
```